# Saleforce list to include data from SQL Server

Tags: list, list-view, sqlserver

I need to create a list in Salesforce that include leads from Lead.com, Radius AND leads from my company’s own list in SQL server.

It seems simple enough to create a list in SF that includes leads from Lead.com and Radius. Is it even possible to merge in data from SQL Server too?

Ultimately, I need to create a “Do not call” list in SF. There is some overlap of data from sql server and lead.com + Radius. I need to ensure that if I already have a lead in SQL server that is marked as a “do not call” lead, that it is marked as do not call in my leads from lead.com and radius too.

Can anyone tell me if this is even possible? And if so, a general overview of steps I would need to take? I know very little about Salesforce, so I would appreciate it in layperson’s terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I dont think you can directly fetch data from sql server.
- Create a api which will fetch the data from sql server.
- Then consume this api in apex class to create data in salesforce.

Comment here, if you need some more information.